# Offline alternative for converting text to images for screen overlays in Google Earth

Tags: html, local, kml, offline, google-earth

I am creating a tool that generates a Google Earth kml that displays time dependent data as screen overlays in a tour.  When running the kml on a machine with access to the internet, I can do this relatively easily using the Google Chart API, and using animate updates to modify the text string within a CDATA section-ed href element within the icon element of the screen overlay for each time step.  Unfortunately, this kml generation tool is to be used primarily offline, and the Google Chart API is not available for offline use due to their ToS.

The only other alternative I have thought of is to create an image file of my desired overlay text for each timestep, and include all of these files in the kml.  But this would result in ~1000 or greater separate image files, and therefore an absolutely massive kml size, and not to mention the run time it would take to generate these image files each time my kml generation tool was ran.

I am seeking an alternative, something similar to the Google Chart API where I can just update an html string to modify my desired text to be overlaid.  I'm not sure if that would take hosting a webpage locally that could do the same thing, or possibly downloading some open source javascript library that I could call to from within my kml (if either of those even makes sense?)

Any suggestions?

This is what my typical call to the Google Chart API looks like:

```
<ScreenOverlay>
    <name>Time Overlay</name>
    <visibility>1</visibility>
    <overlayXY x="1" xunits="fraction" y="1" yunits="fraction"/>
    <screenXY x="0.5" xunits="fraction" y="0.5" yunits="fraction"/>
    <size x=".15" xunits="fraction" y=".03" yunits="fraction"/>
    <Icon id="Time Overlay">
        <href><![CDATA[http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&chld=FFFFFF|14|h|000000|b|17:30:00Z | Mar 24, 2016]]></href>
    </Icon>
  </ScreenOverlay>
```

This is what I would desire:

```
<ScreenOverlay>
    <name>Time Overlay</name>
    <visibility>1</visibility>
    <overlayXY x="1" xunits="fraction" y="1" yunits="fraction"/>
    <screenXY x="0.5" xunits="fraction" y="0.5" yunits="fraction"/>
    <size x=".15" xunits="fraction" y=".03" yunits="fraction"/>
    <Icon id="Time Overlay">
        <href><![CDATA[some other local voodoo magic 17:30:00Z | Mar 24, 2016]]></href>
    </Icon>
  </ScreenOverlay>
```

Comment: I also have thought of making images files for each letter and number, which would then only require 36 image files. I could then overlay each individual letter to spell out my desired text. Doable but extremely tedious.